# Gostaria de saber como achar esse atribute aria-label no xpath em python

Tags: python, xpath

Estou buscando o atributo aria-label utilizando o selenium com o código abaixo, mas não estou encontrando.

```
xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frmKey"]/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').__getattribute__("aria-label=")
print("Resultado")
print(xpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, tenta desse jeito abaixo. O selenium tem um método `get_attribute` que faz exatamente isso, outra coisa não precisa colocar o sinal de igual(=)

```
print("Resultado")
print(xpath.get_attribute('aria-label'))
```